# Recursive regex with text before nested parenthesis

Tags: php, regex, recursion

I have the following text

```
$text = 'This is a test to see if something(try_(this(once))) works';
```

I need to get `something(try_(this(once)))` with regex from the text. I have the following issue

- My nesting will not remain constant, my text can be

  - `something(try_(this(once)))` or
  - `something(try_this(once))` or
  - `something(try_thisonce)`

I have tried a number of regex found across the site, but cannot get it working. Here is the closest I have come

### EXAMPLE 1:

```
$text = 'This is a test to see if something(try_(this(once))) works';
$output = preg_match_all('/(\(([^()]|(?R))*\))/', $text, $out);
?><pre><?php var_dump($out[0]); ?></pre><?php
```

This outputs

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "(try_(this(once)))"
}
```

No matter where I add the word `something`(*for example `'/something(\(([^()]|(?R))*\))/'`  and `'/(\something(([^()]|(?R))*\))/'`*), I get an empty array or `NULL`

### EXAMPLE 2

```
$text2 = 'This is a test to see if something(try_(this(once))) works';
$output2 = preg_match_all('/something\((.*?)\)/', $text2, $out2);
?><pre><?php var_dump($out2[0]); ?></pre><?php
```

With this code I do get the word `something` back,

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(25) "something(try_(this(once)"
}
```

but then the expression stops and return after the first closing `)` which is expected as this is not a recursive expression

How do I recursively match and return a nested parenthesis with the word `something` before the first opening `(`, and if possible, what happens then there might or might not be a whitespace before the word `something`, for example

- `something(try_(this(once)))` or
- `something (try_(this(once)))`

Comment: Why can't you just do this? https://regex101.com/r/jW9iW0/1

Comment: @dustmouse It works as well for `something(try_(this(once))`), but `something (try_(this(once)))` returns nothing. Any idea how to match the whitespace in the event one might or might not occur, post it as an answer please so I can give you some credit

Comment: Okay, I posted an answer that can handle the whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(?R)` isn't a magical incantation to obtain a pattern able to handle balanced things (like parenthesis for example). `(?R)` is the same thing than `(?0)`, it is an alias for "the capture group zero", in other words, the whole pattern.

In the same way you can use `(?1)`, `(?2)`, etc. as aliases for the sub-patterns in group 1, 2, etc.

As an aside, note that except for `(?0)` and `(?R)` that are obviously always in their sub-pattern, since it is the whole pattern, `(?1)`, `(?2)` induce a recursion only if they are in their respective own groups, and can be used only to not rewrite a part of a pattern.

`something\((?:[^()]|(?R))*\)` doesn't work because it imposes each nested (or not) opening parenthesis to be preceded by `something` in your string.

Conclusion, you can't use `(?R)` here, and you need to create a capture group to only handle nested parenthesis:

```
(\((?:[^()]|(?1))*\))
```

that can be written in a more efficient way:

```
(\([^()]*(?:(?1)[^()]*)*+\))
```

To finish you only need to add `something` that is no more included in the recursion:

```
something(\([^()]*(?:(?1)[^()]*)*+\))
```

Note that if `something` is a sub-pattern with an undetermined number of capture groups, it is more handy to refer to the last opened capture group with a relative reference like this:

```
som(eth)ing(\([^()]*(?:(?-1)[^()]*)*+\))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[^() ]*(\((?:[^()]|(?1))*\))
```

You need to use `?1`.`(?1) recurses the 1st subpattern`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/4

Comment: Great, it works for `something(try_(this(once)))`, but `something (try_(this(once)))` returns nothing. Any idea how to match the whitespace in the event one does occur

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty literal way to match the desired text and handle the nested parentheses:

```
something\s*\(.*?\)+
```

https://regex101.com/r/cN6nQ9/1